# Laravel eloquent pagination return duplicate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I have an issue with laravel `withCount` query. Here is my code:

```
Auth::user()->followers()->withCount([
     'posts AS count' => fn($posts) => $posts
        >where('status_id', 1)
       ->whereDoesntHave('views', fn($view) => $view->where('visitor', Auth::id()))

])->orderBy('count', 'DESC')->paginate(8);
```

The problem is when I `get()` this query I have 44 unique users with number of unread posts, But when I paginate I have duplicated user in each page.

Comment: That's the problem i'm having now, maybe you could try cursor based pagination? idk if that helps